# React, can't set the state as a JSON object..?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set the state to a JSON object I get from an endpoint

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
count: 1,
file: "File.db",
language: "EN"
})

let json = fetchJSONObjectFromEndpoint();

setData(json)
```

Nothing gets set, even though the JSON contains all the same fields as my object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the data fetching inside of a `useEffect` hook. To have the fetch run on initial render, you would want something like:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  count: 1,
  file: 'File.db',
  language: 'EN',
});

useEffect(() => {
    const json = await fetchJSONObjectFromEndpoint();
    setData(json)
}, [])
```

Comment: I do, same issue. Works with classes though so I'm good